# AES encryption algorithm not decrypting for few document formats

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt the documents using AES encryption algorithm.

I am getting key from enc file and using it in the algorithm.

When I am trying to decrypt the documents, I am not able to decrypt few format of documents such as `docx, xlsx, pptx and txt` files. Please find my code below.

```
- (NSData *)AES256Decrypt
{

NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:<filename> ofType:@"enc"];

// fetch key data from the key file
NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      [keyData bytes], kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
{
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
}

free(buffer);
return nil;
}
```

I added the above method as category for NSData.

I tried to encrypt and decrypt in client side. Even that document is not able to decrypt properly. When I tried to open decrypted file, I am getting `office open xml word processing document` error when using QLPreviewController to view the document.

I am not able to find why this happening for few documents alone. Can anyone help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to decrypt some but not all files that points to a possible padding issue. I notice that you do not supply `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding`. If the data is other than an even block multiple in size some form of padding is needed. (Sure, a stream cypher like CTR mode could be used but that is a generally a poor choice.)

Using ECB mode (`kCCOptionECBMode`) is really bad, you should really use CBC, the default, along with an iv.

See [Bob ‘n Alice On Security](http://bobnalice.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/friends-don%E2%80%99t-let-friends-use-ecb-mode-encryption/)
[image: Original]
Original

[image: ECB mode]
ECB mode (Eve loves ECB)

[image: CBC mode]
CBC mode

See the difference? Still want to use ECB?

Comment: In server side the algorithm is implemented using ECB mode to encrypt the documents. to change server algorithm is not in my hand too. anyway need to decrypt using this algorithm. thanks.

Comment: Right, I get it: the security is really not all that important. I bet Target said the same thing, that turned out well—oh wait. Look, if you are a professional you do not do this sort of thing: sacrifice security because you are not willing to take a stand. If you are a professional just tell them no. Easy: No—I was almost fired for not accepting poor encryption—but I wasn't. I have never kowtowed and I have never been fired for it. You and many others must learn to stand up for these sort of things. Every time I have done it it has worked out well, I have gained respect. You you can too.

Comment: If we want to be treated like professionals we need to act like professionals.

Comment: I'm sorry to be harsh but security it different. A few bugs in a program (app) is not a killer, it is the rare program that does not have several bugs. But one error in security renders it all useless. An attacker just needs to find one. Here is what suggest: The architect needs to spend substantial time studying crypto related security and then hire a domain expert to review the design and code or hire a domain expert to design expert. I take the first path. I got the company to hire a domain expert to review the security of each project, expect to pay about $2000/day. It is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue that jumps out for me is that you have specified the AES128 algorithm, but have also set up  a key length for the AES256 algorithm. As far as I know, you need to use the key length the matches the algorithm.

I would change the CCrypt call as follows, and see if that handles the issue.

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      [keyData bytes], kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      NULL
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);
```

Alternatively, of course, if your intention is to use AES256, do this:

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES256, kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      [keyData bytes], kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);
```

For decryption, you don't really need to pad the output buffer size, although it certainly doesn't hurt to do so.

Secondly, rather than use malloc for your output buffer, it may be better to use NSMutableData. Here is some code I have used successfully to do a similar thing:

```
NSMutableData * buffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferSize];
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES256, kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      [keyData bytes], kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL
                                      [self bytes],
                                      dataLength,
                                      buffer.mutableBytes,
                                      buffer.length,
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
{
    [buffer setLength:numBytesDecrypted];
    return buffer;
}
return nil;
```

Finally, a great resource for Crypto stuff can be found in Rob Napier's writings. See http://robnapier.net/aes-commoncrypto/ for a start.

Comment: I didn't find any algorithm as you mentioned(kCCAlgorithmAES256). Even in Napier's sample kCCAlgorithmAES128 is used. Can you please check it and let me know. When I tried using the mutable data rather using malloc, decryption that works before is also not working fine.

Comment: Hi Raja -You are correct - I took a look at CommonCrypto.h and I see that that package currently support only 128 bit AES. The point I was making was that the key length must match the block length, and I didn't check to see if there was support in for 256 bit.

Comment: Regarding NSMutableData, if you have other cases where you successfully use malloc for the buffer, I would say it is safe to stick with that. Not sure why NSMutableData doesn't work for you, however. Back to your main problem - are you certain the data provider is using a 256 bit algorithm for the encryption? Have you tried decrypting with the 128 bit algorithm? Also, is it possible the encrypted data may be Base64 encoded, or some other kind of encoding? It is common to encode encrypted data that way for transmission.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem here:

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode,
                                  [keyData bytes], kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                  NULL
                                  [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                  buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                  &numBytesDecrypted);
```

In this code `[keyData bytes]` should be your password. But you are doing this:

```
NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Your document's data should be passed in the argument where you currently have `[self bytes]`.

EDIT:
After seeing your comment, I realize that the file contains the key.

I use AES in one of my projects and I use this code:

```
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char * keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
// fetch key data
[key getCString: (char *)keyPtr maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr) encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In the last line 'key' is my password. And i call the `CCCrypt` function like this:

```
CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                 NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                 [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                 buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                 &numBytesDecrypted );
```

Comment: keyData bytes is password and [self bytes] is the documents. [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] is where i am getting the content of enc file (key file) for key of algorithm. and [self bytes] is the content of the encrypted document.

Comment: ya. me too used the same in one of the project. now i need to use key from the enc file. when i try to use it not able decrypt few documents alone. that's my issue.